# Where do I set screenshots in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, settings, screenshot

OK for this I've searched and searched and can only and I do mean only find info related to how to take a screenshot or where to find them in our systems, but I need to know WHERE to put my screen shot once I've got one - do I add it somewhere in my app in Xcode or somewhere else?

For clarification, I'm talking about setting the screen shot for the image that's shown in the app store, like the application screen shots you'll see here
https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/run-map-my-run-gps-running/id291890420?mt=8

So with that said, are there 2 kinds of screen shots that are needed before submitting my app for approval?

Comment: Do you want to add screenshot to iPhone/iPad simulator?

Comment: Well I don't think so unless that's what's necessary to do before I submit to app - all i know is at that link i put above, and on all apple store app pages, there are screen shots of the app and I don't know where to add those in so once my app is approved they show up. Does that make sense?

Comment: It's not done in the iTunesConnect app settings/uploads is it? I thought those were for the icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The App Store screenshots are added as part of the process of submitting an app in iTunes Connect. They are not added to the app itself, they are uploaded in iTunes Connect.

Comment: I see this now - somewhere in my travels I was lead to believe those are icons - and so I added icon type images, I see now that these are the screen shots and so my apologies for this somewhat wasteful question.